# How to use rbind.data.frame such that the resulting data frame has no row names?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a list containing data frames that I want to merge into one big data frame *without* row names. I tried:

```
ls <- list(df1 = data.frame(col1 = c(1, 2)), df2 = data.frame(col1 = c(3, 4)))
do.call(rbind.data.frame, ls)
```

However, this leads to a data frame with row names:

```
      col1
df1.1    1
df1.2    2
df2.1    3
df2.2    4
```

I also tried `do.call(rbind.data.frame(make.row.names = F), ls)`. But this earned me:

> Error in do.call(rbind.data.frame(make.row.names = F), ls) : 
>     'what' must be a function or character string

**EDIT:** If no easy solution pops up, I will delete the row names in a second step with `rownames(df_goal) <- c(0)`.

Comment: I checked this post, but I can not spot an answer there to my problem.

Comment: `do.call(rbind, c(l, make.row.names = FALSE))`; see the second example in `?do.call`: "if we already have a list [...] we need `c()` to add further arguments"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dplyr::bind_rows(ls)` should give you the expected output.

Option 2: `Reduce(rbind.data.frame, ls)`

Option 3 (for completeness) - suggested by @Henrik: `do.call(rbind, c(ls, make.row.names = FALSE))`